# Flutter geolocator problems

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Всем привет! Когда я импортирую geolocator в свой flutter проект, он перестаёт билдиться. Я думаю что проблема где-то в androidX, но не могу понять где именно.

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема скорее всего в том что вы не сделали миграцию на AndroidX. [Как мигрировать на AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration):

1. Добавьте следующее в файл **«android/gradle.properties»** или **«.android/gradle.properties»**:

   `android.useAndroidX=true 
    android.enableJetifier=true`
2. Убедитесь, что вы установили `compileSdkVersion` в файле **«android/app/build.gradle»**, **28** версии:

   `android { compileSdkVersion 28 ... }`

Также рекомендую обновить Flutter до последней версии, так как начиная с v1.12.13 AndroidX используется по умолчанию для новых проектов.

---

*Если проблема осталось, напишите в комментарии.*

Comment: Я использую новейшую версию flutter и все эти вещи у меня прописаны. Ошибка, к сожалению, не в этом.

Comment: @СтасРыжов да я заметил, в ошибке сказано что отсутствует файл. Возможно поможет следующая команда: flutter clean